# mysql - select all operation (incomes and expenditures) and state after

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

```
inc_header - (id_inc_h, date, user)
inc_list - (id_inc_l, id_inc_h, date, user, quantity) 
expen_header - (id_exp_h, date, user)
expen_list - (id_exp_l, id_exp_h, date, user, quantity)
```

I would like to select all operation and knew what was state after all operation, something like this:

| type_operation | date | user | quantity | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| income | 14.04 | 11 | 100 | 110 |
| expendit | 16.04 | 1 | -30 | 80 |

I know how get except state - I don't how count it.

**Edit**
After Akina sugestion I have something like this

```sql
SELECT income AS type_op, date, user, sum(quantity) over(order by date)
FROM inc_list
UNION
SELECT expen AS type_op, date, user, sum(quantity) over(order by date)
FROM expen_list
```

but it show

| type_operation | date | user | quantity | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| income | 14.04 | 11 | 100 | 110 |
| expendit | 16.04 | 1 | -30 | 30 |
| expendit | 16.04 | 1 | -30 | 60 |
| expendit | 16.04 | 1 | -30 | 90 |

Comment: UNION then cumulative SUM.

Comment: cumulative sum? maybe some short example

Comment: `SUM(column1) OVER (ORDER BY column2)`.

Comment: It mutch better but .... I have edit my post

Comment: No. UNION ALL in subquery, then SUM in outer query.

Comment: sorry but I have no idea how to do it, I'm not good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT type_op, `date`, user, quantity, sum(quantity) over (order by `date`)
FROM ( SELECT 'income' AS type_op, `date`, user, quantity
       FROM inc_list
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'expense', `date`, user, -quantity
       FROM expen_list ) AS total
```

This is the solution for simple case - only one row per date in each table.

If there is more than one row per date in a table then there **must** be a criteria which sets unambiguous relative ordering for the rows. Current dataset does not contain such criteria - so in current state the task cannot be solved unambiguously.

Comment: very very nice, Thank You